# Executar processo em paralelo no PHP

Tags: php, web-service, thread, amazon-aws

Eu possuo um *Web service* que é consumido por algumas aplicações. No servidor do *Web service* deve haver a utilização da *API* da *Amazon* e executar um processo sempre que uma alteração de registro for efetuada via *Web service*.

Inicialmente pensei em executar o processo com Amazon no mesmo momento em que responde ao usuário. O fato é que o serviço da Amazon tende a demorar mais em comparação com a resposta do *Web service* às aplicações, o que poderia resultar em um tempo de resposta alto ao usuário.

Nesse caso pensei em executar em Threads, assim sempre que uma solicitação fosse enviada ao *Web service*, ele iniciaria em paralelo a conexão com a Amazon. Só que existem restrições de recursos no servidor (*Locaweb*) e eu não tenho permissão de instalar complementos (*PECL*).

```
<?php

class workerThread extends Thread {
    public function __construct($i){
        $this->i=$i;
    }

    public function run(){
        while(true){
            echo $this->i;
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
}

for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
    $workers[$i]=new workerThread($i);
    $workers[$i]->start();
}

?>
```

Outra maneira que pensei de fazer seria executar um *cURL*, mas pelo que vi, o tempo de resposta é o mesmo de executar o processo na mesma linha do *Web service*.

Então mestres gurus, com o *PHP*, é possível executar essa comunicação com a *Amazon* em segundo plano e a resposta ao usuário ser enviada no tempo padrão do *Web service* para evitar um tempo de resposta muito alto?

Comment: A maneira mais tradicional seria usar tarefas agendadas (com cron), que executam de tempos em tempos e tratam uma fila do que precisa ser feito no webservice.

Comment: o script principal precisa aguardar a finalização dos processos paralelos ou não?

Comment: não precisa esperar @Sanção

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Para executar um processo em paralelo, siga os passos abaixo.

Você citou que a hospedagem está na Locaweb e a função `exec` é bloqueada nos servidores Windows deles. Já vi outras empresas que bloqueam essa função. Então esta resposta **só funciona em Linux**. Para Windows é possivel adaptar com o código [dessa resposta (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031171/how-to-run-a-command-on-the-background-on-windows#21031259).

Crie um arquivo php com o processo que deve ser executado em segundo plano, nesse exemplo será `thread.php`

No arquivo que vai iniciar a *thread* inclua:

```
exec('php diretorio/thread.php >> diretorio_logs/arquivo_de_log.log 2>&1 &');
```

A função `exec` executa em linha de comando a *string* passada como parâmetro.

O operador `>>` salva tudo o que `thread.php` exibir com *echo* (*printf*, etc.) no arquivo especificado. A parte `2>&1` redireciona a saída de erros (*stderr*) para a saída padrão (*stdout*), então qualquer coisa que for exibida por `thread.php` será salva em `arquivo_de_log.log`, inclusive eventuais erros.

Se a saída de `thread.php` pode ser descartada utilize apenas:

```
exec('php diretorio/thread.php &');
```

O `&` no final é responsável por iniciar a execução do processo em segundo plano. Com esse modificador, o comando é executado e o processo que chamou o comando **não** aguarda a sua conclusão.

---

existe uma extensão do PHP para controle de processos que também pode ser utilizada: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pcntl.php

Comment: Estou familiarizado com o shell, linux e seus comandos, e não me atentei a esse detalhe, realmente eu posso executar comandos shell via php. Creio que sua solução depende de colocar no cabeçalho do arquivo a seguinte linha: #!/usr/bin/php -q. Estou certo @Sanção?

Comment: @touchmx vi a necessidade desse cabeçalho somente para executar comandos pelo PHP em modo CGI [nessa página wiki da Locaweb](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Como_utilizar_a_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_PHP_shell_exec%28%29), quando utilizei esse processo não foi necessário incluir o cabeçalho (ambiente Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 4):

Uma rotina que executa processos em background:

```
class Background
{

    /*
    $cmd -> A linha de comando a executar.
    $opt -> Opção de parâmetros para o ambiente onde executa o script.
    */
    public static function Call($cmd, $opt = 'start')
    {

        if (stripos(php_uname('s'), 'windows') !== false) {
            /*
            Condições de parâmetros para ambiente Windows.
            */
            switch ($opt) {
                default:
                case 'start':
                    $prefix = 'start /B '; // Esse aqui é o padrão, pois é compatível com as versões mais recentes do Windows.
                    $sufix = '';
                    break;
                case 'nul':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' > NUL 2> NUL';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            /*
            Opções para ambiente *nix. (isso inclui os-x)
            Normalmente o sufixo ` &` é compatível com diversas distribuições Linux. Esse parâmetro diz ao sistema operacional executar em background.
            */
            switch ($opt) {
                default:
                case '&':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' &';
                    break;
                case 'dev-null':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';
                    break;
            }
        }

        exec(sprintf('%s%s%s', $prefix, $cmd, $sufix));

        return null;
    }

}

define('PHP_PATH', '/local/do/binario/php');

echo 'start '.microtime(true);
Background::Call(PHP_PATH.' "/local/de/um/arquivo.php"');
Background::Call(PHP_PATH.' "/local/de/um/arquivo.php"');
Background::Call(PHP_PATH.' "/local/de/um/arquivo.php"');
echo PHP_EOL.'end '.microtime(true);
```

**arquivo.php**

```
<?php

/*
Fecha o output, ou seja, faz com que o script que invocou, não fique esperando por uma resposta.
*/
fclose(STDOUT);

/*
Daqui em diante, pode fazer o que bem entender.
Claro, esteja ciente de que tudo aqui está sendo executado em ambiente CLI (Command Line Interface).

Vamos fazer uma simulação e testar se está funcionando.
*/

file_put_contents('background.txt', 'start '.microtime(true).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
sleep(5); // espera 5 segundos
file_put_contents(BASE_DIR.'background.txt', 'end '.microtime(true).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

**Sobre a rotina de execução assíncrona**

Não há um controle dos processos. Basicamente é enviado um comando de execução pela função `exec()`, que combinado com alguns parâmetros ignora o retorno de uma resposta. Perfazendo assim, execuções assíncronas.

As combinações variam de acordo com o ambiente, portanto, esteja ciente de que não basta apenas copiar o código e pensar que vai funcionar como mágica.

No método `Call()` da classe `Background`, basta adicionar parâmetros novos se necessário.

Exemplo:

```
            /*
            Opções para ambiente *nix. (isso inclui os-x)
            Normalmente o sufixo ` &` é compatível com diversas distribuições Linux. Esse parâmetro diz ao sistema operacional executar em background.
            */

            switch ($opt) {
                default:
                case '&':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' &';
                    break;
                case 'dev-null':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';
                    break;
                case 'dev-null2':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' /dev/null 2>&1 &';
                    break;
                case 'outro-nome-como-quiser':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' /algum/comando/diferente/que/funcione/num/ambiente/especifico';
                    break;
            }
```

O script é simples, limpo, fácil de entender. Não depende de bibliotecas terceiras.

Comment: Sensacional! Obrigado