# Consumir vários WebServices com PHP ao mesmo tempo (SOAP e REST)

Tags: php, web-service, rest, soap

Basicamente, eu preciso consumir vários Web Services e, em seguida, fazer um merge dos resultados.

Eu estava usando [cURL com PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) pra fazer as requisições, mas conforme o número de Web Services aumentou, o meu serviço ficou mais lento, já que era necessário esperar por uma resposta e, só depois, fazer o pedido para o próximo Web Service.

Eu resolvi esse problema usando [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) e tudo estava funcionando corretamente.

O que acontece é que eu tenho novos Web Services para adicionar ao meu serviço, mas esses novos usam o protocolo [SOAP](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/) e eu não estou conseguindo mais fazer requests simultâneos, porque pra consultar Web Services SOAP eu uso [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) e não cURL.

Eu sei que eu posso fazer o XML do SOAP "na mão" e depois enviá-lo junto com os outros usando cURL, mas isso me parece uma má prática.

Resumindo, há alguma maneira de consumir Web Services REST e SOAP simultaneamente com PHP?

Fiz esta mesma pergunta no [SO_en](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478050/consuming-several-webservices-with-php-at-the-same-time-soap-and-rest), mas não obtive nenhuma resposta.

Comment: minha sugestão (não me parece uma prática muito boa, mas deve resolver), é consumir o WebService SOAP em uma *thread* usando o código existente, a parte negativa é ter que armazenar o resultado da *thread* (BD ou arquivo, sessão não deve funcionar) e sincronizar o retorno manualmente. Olhe [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56598/13561).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica @Sanção. Eu pensei em [usar threads também](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087340/threads-in-php-and-apache), mas esbarrei em outros problemas com essa abordagem. Vou analisar o link que você me passou, não havia considerado chamar um .php através do exec, mas pode funcionar, mesmo parecendo uma má prática como você bem observou.