# Como chamar uma função sem esperar ela terminar?

Tags: php, multithreading

Preciso chamar uma função no PHP que grava vários registros no banco de dados o que vai demorar muito, preciso que ela faça em "segundo plano" enquanto o PHP faça outra coisa, é possível? Se sim, como fazer?

Comment: Relacionado: [Executar processo em paralelo no PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56446/91)

Comment: Temos 2 ou 3 questões no site que tratam de executar operações demoradas com PHP via linha de comando + crontab. Provavelmente é uma solução melhor pelo que você descreve. Nada impede da aplicação online por algo em uma fila para que a tarefa em BG execute. Geralmente é melhor do que paralelismo por thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar a classe [Thread](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.thread.php) do PHP:

```
<?php

class segundoPlano extends Thread 
{
    public function __construct($sP)
    {
        $this->sP = $sP;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        //o teu código a executar;
    }
}

$segundoP = new segundoPlano($sP);
$segundoP->start();
```

A variável no construtor é um exemplo.

*Nota: Para utilizar esta classe tem de ser instalar a [extensão pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php).*