# PHPMailer muito lento para enviar emails

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Estou usando o `PHPMailer` em um host da GoDaddy, a página de cadastro demora cerca de 10~15 segundos só para enviar o e-mail, existe alguma forma eficiente para otimizar isto? ou é uma questão de capacidade do servidor?

Configuração atual:

```
    $Mailer = new PHPMailer;

    $Mailer -> isSMTP();
    $Mailer -> CharSet = MAIL_CHARSET;
    $Mailer -> SMTPSecure = MAIL_SECURE;
    $Mailer -> Host = MAIL_HOST;
    $Mailer -> Port = MAIL_SMTP_PORT;
    $Mailer -> SMTPAuth = true;

    $Mailer -> Username = MAIL_USER;
    $Mailer -> Password = MAIL_PASSWORD;

    // REMETENTE
    $Mailer -> From = 'xxxxxxx';
    $Mailer -> FromName = 'xxxxxx';
    //CORPO DA MSG
    $Mailer -> Subject = $title;
    $Mailer -> msgHTML($message);
    $Mailer -> isHTML(true);

    // DESTINATÁRIO
    $Mailer -> addAddress($email);
```

Answer (score 2):

É um tempo muito alto mesmo para um email autenticado. Normalmente 1 a 4 segundos é algo razoável mas ainda assim incômodo. Nesse meio tempo o usuário fica anioso e impaciente. Manda atualizar a página, faz envios duplicados, etc, gerando ainda mais trafego.

Uma tática para reduzir esse custo de tempo de espera no lado do usuario, é gerar um agendamento no servidor para enviar logo em seguida no primeiro minuto. Assim a requisição voltará ao browser do usuário em alguns milisegundos. Enquanto isso, o agendamento no servidor "cuidará" da execução. Alternativamente ao agendamento é criar uma execução em background pois agendamentos dependem de permissões do servidor de hospedagem.

Sobre o problema descrito na pergunta é inviável determinar o que realmente acontece. Pode ser má configuração do ambiente do servidor ou simplesmente uma capacidade limitada.

Devido ao alto tempo de espera, sugiro que consulte o suporte do servidor pois não é um tempo de espera normal mesmo em servidores baratos compartilhados.

Esteja ciente também que a autenticação do email depende de um terceiro servidor, o servidor SMTP com o qual está autenticando, portanto, pode ser uma falha ou congestionamento nesse servidor SMTP e pode ser algo momentâneo. Você pode testar isso configurando o envio para outros servidores SMTP distintos. Exemplo, se está tenstando com gmail, teste com live mail, yahoo ou qualquer outro particular. Se todos os outros demoram muito tempo, então é provável que há algo "anormal" no servidor de hospedagem.

De qualquer forma, envio de email sempre custa um tempo. Procure criar agendamento ou técnicas de execução em background (assíncrona).

Para execução asssíncrona, consulte: [Executar processo em paralelo no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56446/executar-processo-em-paralelo-no-php)

Comment: O test que você fala com gmail, live mail e yahoo mail seriam os destinatários, certo? porque ja vi alguns exemplos por ai deles sendo usados como "host" , não entendi muito bem

Comment: vc parece confuso pois está misturando as coisas..  O teste é trocar o smtp de autenticação do remetente..