# Enviar e-mails em background PHP

Tags: php

Possuo um sistema de cadastro de usuários, e após o usuário ter se cadastrado é necessário confirmar a conta no e-mail, o problema é que a página demora um pouco para carregar e isso pode gerar um pouco de inquietação ou até confundir o usuário (pela demora pode pensar que algo está errado), de algumas linguagens tinha conhecimento que algumas coisas eram rodadas em segundo plano, mas nunca soube nada pelo php, existe alguma forma de enviar e-mails pelo background com php? Estou usando o PHPMailer e um servidor local WAMP, e Linux no Host na web.

Comment: relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170109/phpmailer-muito-lento-para-enviar-emails

Comment: Você pode fazer com Ajax + php. Põe um gif de loading e pronto, está feita a mágica.