# Ler conteúdo de uma pasta e processar os arquivos de forma assíncrona

Tags: php

Tenho uma pasta com vários `XML`.

Gostaria que um script fizesse a leitura destes arquivos, e processasse cada um deles.

---

Como faço para **ler o conteúdo da pasta** e "puxar os arquivos", já que **são nomes diferentes** ?

Teria como fazer isso de **forma assíncrona**, assim, processando mais de 1 ao mesmo tempo, e setando um limite de processos simultâneos, evitando travar o processamento ?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
$array = glob('caminho/ate/a/pasta/*.xml');
```

Você pode definir alguns padrões de pasta e utilizar o asterísco para definir coringas, aonde qualquer caracter, ou quantidade deles, será retornado.

Ou seja, o código acima retornará qualquer arquivo, dentro daquele caminho, que possua a extensão `.xml`.

Outra ideia é usar os [`GlobIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php) da SPL:

```
$iterator = new GlobIterator('caminho/ate/a/pasta/*.xml');

foreach ($iterator as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

Ou algum outro iterator abaixo:

- [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php);
- [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php);

Todos chegarão no resultado que deseja, mas, específico para busca de arquivos é o [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) ou [`GlobIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/globiterator.construct.php).

**Processamento Paralelo**

Para o processamento em paralelo, há três formas que eu conheço:

- [PHP: Thread](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.thread.php);
- Executar o script via [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php);
- Threads distribuídas.

**PHP Thread**

De forma bem simplista, deve-se extender a classe Thread e definir o processamento do arquivo:

```
class XmlProcessThread extends Thread {

    protected $filename;

    public function __construct($filename) { 
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function run() {
        /** utiliza o filename e reealiza o processamento **/
    }
}
```

Quando for chamar o processamento, deverá instanciar cada Thread iniciando a sua execução:

```
foreach ($fileList as $filename) {
    $thread = new XmlProcessThread($filename);
    $thread->start();
    $threadList[] = $thread;
}
```

**Script via Exec**

Basicamente, você pode executar arquivos PHP utilizando o comando [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Na chamada do script (linha de comando), você deve adicionar como último parâmetro o símbolo `&`, isso faz com que o script seja executado em segundo plano e o script PHP (aquele que iniciou a execução) não espere pelo execução completa.

```
exec('php diretorio/thread.php filename.xml &');
```

No arquivo `thread.php`, deve-se utilizar o a variável [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php). Ela conterá todos os parâmetros enviados para o script (no caso, `filename.xml`).

Mais informações: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56598/5007

**Threads distribuídas**

Neste método, você deve criar [sockets](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), aonde cada socket irá processar um arquivo, e estes sockets devem ser executados via Thread (conforme o primeiro exemplo).

Leituras:

- [Processamento distribuido em PHP utilizando Gearman – Parte 1](https://imasters.com.br/artigo/21385/php/processamento-distribuido-em-php-utilizando-gearman-parte-1/?trace=1519021197&source=single)
- [Processamento distribuído em PHP utilizando Gearman – Parte 2](https://imasters.com.br/artigo/21387/php/processamento-distribuido-em-php-utilizando-gearman-parte-2/?trace=1519021197&source=single)
- [Sistemas Distribuídos em PHP - Diana Arnos - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exf0HPoV1MA)
- [PHP distribuído e paralelo: multithread, stream sockets e docker](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rROcpeFDQaw)
- [Parallel Processing / Task Distribution with PHP](http://code.hootsuite.com/parallel-processing-task-distribution-with-php/)

**Qual é melhor?**

Bem, sempre depende. Normalmente tendem a ter resultados diferentes para cenários diferentes.

Por exemplo, o processamento paralelo distribuído tende a ser mais rápido em casos que demandem muito processamento (horas de processamento). Pois, distribui o processamento em outros servidores. Entretanto, neste caso, pode exigir o envio do arquivo para o outro servidor (caso o arquivo não esteja no alcance dele) e ser custoso para o processamento final.

Por outro lado, Thread e exec utiliza o mesmo servidor e os processos irão competir entre si, o que provavelmente sacrificará a performance.

Isso são apenas alguns dos exemplos sobre vantagens e desvantagens. Um boa visão você pode tirar da resposta abaixo:

[É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1957/5007)

Comment: Muito bom Gabriel, não conhecia nem um nem outro. Mas e no caso de ser assíncrono? por exemplo: cada arquivo iria processar separadamente, com um limite de 5 processos simultâneos

Comment: @RBZ Então, eu vi agora que você atualizou sua resposta. Tem um artigo muito bom sobre processamento assíncrono e distribuído, com exemplo específico de XML. Estou pesquisando ele aqui.